# Dynamically centering UIImagepicker viewfinder that has been scaled up to full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm making a full screen camera for the iPhone 5 and have the following code to scale the 4:3 camera to fill the entire screen, which is a 2:3 ratio. The left and right sides bleed off the screen.

I have to move the cameraView down 71 points in order for it to center with the screen. Otherwise, there's a black bar at the bottom. I'm not quite sure why. Because I don't know why this is happening, I can't figure out how to dynamically code the adjustment to accommodate the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

Any help is appreciated.

```
// get the screen size
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

// establish the height to width ratio of the camera
float heightRatio = 4.0f / 3.0f;

// calculate the height of the camera based on the screen width
float cameraHeight = screenSize.width * heightRatio;

// calculate the ratio that the camera height needs to be scaled by
float ratio = screenSize.height / cameraHeight;

//This slots the preview exactly in the middle of the screen by moving it down 71 points (for iphone 5)
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 71.0);
self.camera.cameraViewTransform = translate;

CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, ratio, ratio);
self.camera.cameraViewTransform = scale;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finally clicked in my head. Since we know that the camera will always be the same length of the screen width:

//getting the camera height by the 4:3 ratio

```
int cameraViewHeight = SCREEN_WIDTH * 1.333;

int adjustedYPosition = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - cameraViewHeight) / 2;

CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, adjustedYPosition);
self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = translate;
```